# coupling by using dp

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given two strings, S1 & S2. given scoring scheme where gap penalty, mismatch score and match score.

Find the S1 which have a best match with S2.

My idea is to list all possible S1 and then match one by one with S2. List all possible S1 by using brute force. Then match each possible S1 with S2 by using dp.

Is there is any faster way to do so? or suggest any reference?

Comment: What is "best match"? Can 'a', ..., 'f' be reused for several 'x'?

Comment: The question is not clear, are you referring to the longest common subsequence (ie. non-contiguous)?

Comment: Without defining the "degree of matchingness" function, all you can do is try every possibility and see which gets the highest score.

Comment: @Steve Jessop, yes..the degree of matchingness is not given, so my idea is correct right?or got any faster way?

Comment: @savinos, yes..something like longest common subsequence..

Comment: @rock: I don't even really see how you'll use dynamic programming in that case. As you say there are `6^i` possible results. You have to feed every single one of them into the black box that tells you their score, since the score of one string tells you absolutely nothing about the score of any other string. It's like finding the max of an unsorted array, it's unavoidably O(n) (where n == 6^i in this case), with the only possible exception being that if the score is given in a finite type like `int`, and you encounter `INT_MAX`, you can stop early.

Comment: Have you looked at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#Code_for_the_dynamic_programming_solution ? Also, TopCoder has a nice series of posts on the topic, including a solution to the LCS problem: http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=dynProg&module=Static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Wikipedia and a little bit of thinking one could code up something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef MAX
#define MAX(a,b) ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))
#endif

#define MATCH_SCORE     2
#define MISMATCH_SCORE  -1
#define GAP_SCORE       0

// Calculates the match score recursively.
long MatchScore(const char* p/* in: may contain 'x' */,
                const char* s/* in: doesn't contain 'x' */)
{
  long res;

  if (*p && *s)
  {
    if ((*p == *s) ||
        ((*p == 'x') && (*s >= 'a') && (*s <= 'f')))
    {
      res = MatchScore(p + 1, s + 1) + MATCH_SCORE;
    }
    else
    {
      long s1 = MatchScore(p + 1, s + 1) + MISMATCH_SCORE;
      long s2 = MatchScore(p, s + 1) + GAP_SCORE;
      long s3 = MatchScore(p + 1, s) + GAP_SCORE;
      res = MAX(s1, MAX(s2, s3));
    }
  }
  else
  {
    res = GAP_SCORE * (long)(strlen(p) + strlen(s));
  }

  return res;
}

// Calculates the best matching string and the match score
// using dynamic programming, the score must be the same
// as returned by MatchScore().
void FindBestMatch(const char* p/* in: may contain 'x' */,
                   const char* s/* in: doesn't contain 'x' */,
                   long* score/* out: match score */,
                   char** match/* out: best matching string */)
{
  size_t lp = strlen(p) + 1;
  size_t ls = strlen(s) + 1;
  size_t i, j;
  long* table = (long*)malloc(lp * ls * sizeof(long));

  for (i = 0; i < lp; i++)
    table[0 * lp + i] = GAP_SCORE * i;

  for (j = 0; j < ls; j++)
    table[j * lp + 0] = GAP_SCORE * j;

  for (j = 1; j < ls; j++)
  {
    for (i = 1; i < lp; i++)
    {
      if ((p[i-1] == s[j-1]) ||
          ((p[i-1] == 'x') && (s[j-1] >= 'a') && (s[j-1] <= 'f')))
      {
        table[j * lp + i] = table[(j-1) * lp + (i-1)] + MATCH_SCORE;
      }
      else
      {
        table[j * lp + i] =
          MAX(table[(j-1) * lp + (i-1)] + MISMATCH_SCORE,
              MAX(table[(j-1) * lp + i] + GAP_SCORE,
                  table[j * lp + (i-1)] + GAP_SCORE));
      }
    }
  }

  *score = table[lp * ls - 1];

  // Now, trace back the score table and construct the best matching string

  *match = (char*)malloc(lp);
  (*match)[lp - 1] = '\0';

  for (j = ls, i = lp; j || i;)
  {
    if ((p[i-1] == s[j-1]) ||
        ((p[i-1] == 'x') && (s[j-1] >= 'a') && (s[j-1] <= 'f')))
    {
      (*match)[i-1] = s[j-1];
      j--;
      i--;
    }
    else
    {
      if (table[(j-1) * lp + i] > table[j * lp + (i-1)])
      {
        j--;
      }
      else
      {
        (*match)[i-1] = p[i-1];
        i--;
      }
    }
  }

  free(table);
}

int main(void)
{
  const char* pattern = "acdxdcxecxf";
  const char* str = "abdfdaaed";
  long score;
  char* match;
  char* match2;

  printf("pattern=\"%s\" str=\"%s\"\n", pattern, str);
  FindBestMatch(pattern, str, &score, &match);
  printf("score=%ld (recursive)\n", MatchScore(pattern, str));
  printf("score=%ld best match=\"%s\"\n", score, match);

  // Now repeat with the best match we've just found,
  // the result must be the same
  printf("\nRepeating with pattern=best match:\n\n");

  printf("pattern=\"%s\" str=\"%s\"\n", match, str);
  FindBestMatch(match, str, &score, &match2);
  printf("score=%ld (recursive)\n", MatchScore(match, str));
  printf("score=%ld best match=\"%s\"\n", score, match2);

  free(match);
  free(match2);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
pattern="acdxdcxecxf" str="abdfdaaed"
score=14 (recursive)
score=14 best match="acdfdcaecdf"

Repeating with pattern=best match:

pattern="acdfdcaecdf" str="abdfdaaed"
score=14 (recursive)
score=14 best match="acdfdcaecdf"
```

I wonder if there're any bugs (other than the apparent lack of error checking).